# How can i kill the process in rabbit mq?

Tags: python, deep-learning, process, rabbitmq

I'm testing AI model with rabbit mq.
Becasue the process using AI model is heavy, i use rabbit mq to control the task order.
The problem is killing the callback function after consuming.
For example, there are three tasks in rabbit mq(A,B,C in order)

1. task A is consuming, callback function(include AI model) is running
2. task B,C is waiting untill basic_ack arrived
3. I want cancel task A ,B and analysis C first

in this case,

1. how can i kill the process (task A),
2. delete the message B in rabbit MQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way but cannot sure the right way.
Use another queue to receive all message from rabbitmq
and create_task by using asyncio to cancel when i want
it works well only all funcs are asyncronose